# Find mfc mainframe OnCommand message for "33614080"

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

Edit 3: This is no good--the Right arrow key is sent every time the window loses focus--bad behavior.

I tried intercepting when the user clicks the close box, but so far I have not been able to find it in the class wizard. If anyone knows how to detect this event, please let me know.

Original post(s):

Edit 2:  I have edited the code for a solution that does not use a magic number, but as Mark Ransom has noted, this is not the proper way to select a specific button for an input prompt, so this may work correctly, but it is a hack.

I have a legacy application in MFC that has a prompt when exiting to save changes.  When the input prompt opens, the 'No' button should be selected when it prompts the user to save changes in the CMainFrame window. This is so that the user can press the Enter key to exit without having to use the mouse to select it. And yes, I am aware that the user can simply press the 'N' key to activate the 'No' button, but the 'No' button needs be selected so the user can press the Enter key to exit.

Using the message loop in:

```
BOOL CMainFrame::OnCommand(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

I can detect a message when the window is closing, before being prompted to save changes.

So I added this numeric value and I am sending the right arrow key to select 'No' in the input message prompt.

EDIT: Added beginning of switch statement to show what is being evaluated.

```
// this is part of 'BOOL CMainFrame::OnCommand(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)' 
BOOL CMainFrame::OnCommand(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
switch( wParam )
{
...
//case 33614080:
    //SendRightArrowKey();
    //break;
default:
    WORD loWord = LOWORD(wParam);
    if (ID_RECORD_FIRST == loWord)
    {
        WORD HiWord = HIWORD(wParam);
        unsigned short value = HiWord;
        char buff[32];
        _itoa(value, buff, 10);
        if (EN_KILLFOCUS == value )
        {
            SendRightArrowKey();
        }           
        return TRUE;
    }
}

return CFrameWnd::OnCommand(wParam, lParam);
}


void SendRightArrowKey()
{
    INPUT output[2];
    ZeroMemory(&output, sizeof(output));
    // Right arrow key down
    output[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    output[0].ki.wVk = VK_RIGHT;
    output[0].ki.time = 0;
    output[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    // Right arrow key up
    output[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    output[1].ki.wVk = VK_RIGHT;
    output[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    output[1].ki.time = 0;
    output[1].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    int retval1 = SendInput(2, output, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

This works for win32 and x64, but it feels like a hack--especially because I can't find any definition for the numeric code 33614080.  There should be constant or a macro for the windows message that gets sent for the WParam, in case Microsoft ever changes this value.

> Does anyone know of a constant that this WParam value might represent,
> or another way to have the 'No' button selected by default?
>
> Thanks in advance for any replies.

Thanks Adrian for figuring out the values.

Comment: 0x 0200 E900 might make more sense. Could be a bunch of codes packed together. Agree that's a hack. Magic number are evil. If that's a compound, use the constants and OR them.

Comment: The 0xE900 (low word) is `ID_RECORD_FIRST ` (in `afxres.h`). No idea what that actually is, or what the 0x0200 (high word) represents (not being 0 or 1, it *should* be a notification code, which is `EN_KILLFOCUS`)...

Comment: Thanks guys, much appreciated.  Now that I know the low word I should be able to find the other value this weekend when I have time. It probably is EN_KILLFOCUS, because focus goes to the input message prompt.  There might be way to override the prompt, but sending the arrow key seems to do the job.  But I don't want to release this yet.

Comment: You show the `case 33614080`, but what is the corresponding switch?

Comment: Sending a right arrow key is absolutely the wrong way to handle this.  You can set the focus to any control you want, directly.

Comment: Oh and MFC has message map macros so you can specify the action for individual commands instead of handling them all in OnCommand.  You should learn how those work.

Comment: Thanks Mark, good points all around.  This is an old legacy project, and I'm not sure its worth putting too much development into this, but in any case I will update the code with what I found.   
 
The HiWord is EN_KILLFOCUS.

Comment: Mark, the OnCommand method for handling messages was part of this project when I inherited it, so I will likely leave it as is, but thanks for the advice.

Comment: OK, anyone know how to detect when the user presses the close box red x in the top-right corner of a window?

Comment: That would be a [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand) with a wParam of `SC_CLOSE`.  If you need to know more you should open a new question.